# Symfony - Driver are mandatory if PDO instance

Tags: composer-php, macos-sierra, php-7, symfony-2.1

I have a project in Symfony 2.1
I'm trying to run Composer install and it gives me this error:

> The options 'driver' or 'driverClass' are mandatory if PDO instance is
>   given to DriverManager :: getConnection ().

The system is:

Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29)

PHP 7.0.22 (cli) (built: Sep 14 2017 09:01:19) (NTS)

Composer version 1.2.2

The Database configuration in Symfony in parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
     database_driver: pdo_mysql
     database_host: 127.0.0.1
     database_port: ~
     database_name: myDatabaseName
     database_user: myDatabaseUser
     database_password: myDatabasePassword
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Please also show the `doctrine` section of your `config.yml` file.

Comment: Sorry. My Doctrine configuration  is:

`# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
'